# Why gulp-watch doesn't delete files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to make my gulp-watch task to delete files from `/dest` directory when I delete them from `/src`, but it doesn't work.
Where is the mistake?

```js
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var del = require('del');
var pngquant = require('gulp-pngquant');

var imgSrc = 'src/img/**';
var imgDst = 'build/img';

gulp.task('del', function() {
  return del('build');

});

gulp.task('img', function() {
  return gulp.src(imgSrc)
    .pipe(debug({title: 'src'}))
    //.pipe(newer(imgDst))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(debug({title: 'imagemin'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDst))
    .pipe(debug({title: 'dest'}));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    var watcher = gulp.watch(imgSrc, ['img']);

    watcher.on('change', function (event) {
        if (event.type === 'deleted') {
            var filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve(imgSrc), event.path);
            var destFilePath = path.resolve(imgDst, filePathFromSrc);
            del.sync(destFilePath);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't understand why are you deleting file in gulp-watch. Better to use delete before build starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `destFilePath` points to a file that doesn't exist. If you delete a file `src/img/foo.png` your `destFilePath` variable ends up pointing to `build/foo.png` instead of `build/img/foo.png` (which is where your `img` task has put it).

The reason is that you're applying `path.relative()` to `imgSrc` which contains `**`. However `path.relative()` doesn't unterstands globs. It just interprets `**` as a regular directory name. So you end up being one directory off.

You need to leave out the `**` when you use `path.relative()`:

```
if (event.type === 'deleted') {
    var filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve('src/img'), event.path);
    var destFilePath = path.resolve(imgDst, filePathFromSrc);
    del.sync(destFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it resolved the problem. But there is another one appeared. When I start gulp-watch with an empty src/img nothing happens (gulp-imagemin doesn't start when I add files to src/img), when I start with images in src/img it begins to work only after deleting the file. I'm new to JS, so it would be great if you can give me an explanation

Comment: I don't have an explanation. What you're describing shouldn't happen. I used your gulpfile to see if I can reproduce the problem and adding files to `src/img` always results in the `img` task running (whether `src/img` is empty or not).